# Nan output for percent calculation, dice rolling program

Tags: c

I'm trying to calculate the the percentage of times two dice were rolled for each total of the two dice. My "actual" value is returning nan, and my expected is returning 0. I know the code is inefficient, we aren't allowed to use arrays in this assignment Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main() {


    int d2 = 0;
    int d3 = 0;
    int d4 = 0;
    int d5 = 0;
    int d6 = 0;
    int d7 = 0;
    int d8 = 0;
    int d9 = 0;
    int d10 = 0;
    int d11 = 0;
    int d12 = 0;


int k, roll_1, roll_2, num_roll, total, count = 0 ;

    float perc, exp;
    srand((long)time(NULL));

    printf("Enter number \n");

    scanf("%d", &num_roll);




for (k = 0; k < num_roll; k++)

            {
            roll_1 = rand() %6 +1;
            roll_2 = rand() %6 +1;
            total = roll_1 + roll_2;
            total++;

            if (total == 2) d2++;
            else if (total == 3) d3++;
            else if (total == 4) d4++;
            else if (total == 5) d5++;
            else if (total == 6) d6++;
            else if (total == 7) d7++;
            else if (total == 8) d8++;
            else if (total == 9) d9++;
            else if (total == 10) d10++;
            else if (total == 11) d11++;
            else if (total == 12) d12++;
     }

printf("Roll\t Total\t Session\tExpected\n\n");


     printf("2:\t %d\t %.3f \t\t %.3f \n", d2, perc, exp);
     printf("3:\t %d\t %.3f \t\t %.3f \n", d3, perc, exp);
     printf("4:\t %d\t %.3f \t\t %.3f \n", d4, perc, exp);
     printf("5:\t %d\t %.3f \t\t %.3f \n", d5, perc, exp);
     printf("6:\t %d\t %.3f \t\t %.3f \n", d6, perc, exp);
     printf("7:\t %d\t %.3f \t\t %.3f \n", d7, perc, exp);
     printf("8:\t %d\t %.3f \t\t %.3f \n", d8, perc, exp);
     printf("9:\t %d\t %.3f \t\t %.3f \n", d9, perc, exp);
     printf("10:\t %d\t %.3f \t\t %.3f \n", d10, perc, exp);
     printf("11:\t %d\t %.3f \t\t %.3f \n", d11, perc, exp);
     printf("12:\t %d\t %.3f \t\t %.3f \n", d2, perc, exp);

  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: what is the output you get?

Comment: It outputs nan for the percents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The `total++` seems wrong; what is that for?
2. You never assign anything to `perc` or `exp`.
3. You print out `d2` twice, but never `d12`.

You should probably turn on some warnings.  With `-Wall`, clang says:

```
example.c:22:41: warning: unused variable 'count' [-Wunused-variable]
int k, roll_1, roll_2, num_roll, total, count = 0 ;
                                        ^
example.c:58:48: warning: variable 'perc' is uninitialized when used here
      [-Wuninitialized]
     printf("2:\t %d\t %.3f \t\t %.3f \n", d2, perc, exp);
                                               ^~~~
example.c:24:15: note: initialize the variable 'perc' to silence this warning
    float perc, exp;
              ^
               = 0.0
example.c:58:54: warning: variable 'exp' is uninitialized when used here
      [-Wuninitialized]
     printf("2:\t %d\t %.3f \t\t %.3f \n", d2, perc, exp);
                                                     ^~~
example.c:24:20: note: initialize the variable 'exp' to silence this warning
    float perc, exp;
                   ^
                    = 0.0
3 warnings generated.
```

Adding `-Weverything` yields one more warning:

```
example.c:25:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to
      'unsigned int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    srand((long)time(NULL));
    ~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

That one you may or may not care about.

Comment: introducing @CarlNorum, your personal debugger :D

Comment: Carl; Which compiler are you using. It seems that it is very easy to debug code with such compiler (or options, if any).

Comment: @CarlNorum; Did't noticed that :)